# Indicar a una función de mongodb que se realice de forma síncrona

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Tengo este código y necesito que el tipoUsuario se guarde cuando lo recoge de la BD, pero como por defecto lo realiza de forma asíncrona se ejecuta al final:

```
function mostrarDatos(){
  MongoClient.connect(urlMongo, {useUnifiedTopology: true ,fsync: true}, function(error, db) {
    if (error) console.log('Error de Mongo: ' + error);
    db.db("test").collection("test").find(sentencia).toArray(function(error, result) {
      if (error) throw error;
      try{
          tipo = result[0].tipo;
          console.log("Dentro" + tipo);
      }catch(error){
          paginaError(response);
      }
    })
  });
  console.log("Fuera" + tipo);
  return tipo;
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar un poco más a fondo donde se declara la variable tipo y como quieres que devuelva el valor? Creo que tamibén es interesante desacoplar código que no tiene que ver con la acción de tu función. La conexión a bbdd debería hacerse en otra capa

Comment: la declaro al comienzo del script y la solución es sencilla, hacer que la función de Mongo se realice de forma síncrona ya que se realiza de forma asíncrona y la recogida de datos se realiza para el final.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrarnos donde declaras la variable tipo?

Comment: Al inicio de la función:

function mostrarDatos(){

let tipo = 0;

Comment: En el ejemplo del código que suministras no está declarada la variable. Voy a preparar un ejemplo pero te recomendaría que la conexión a la base de datos no la hicieras en ese método porque no tiene mucho sentido que lo hagas ahí. Podrías indicarnos un poco más que tipo de aplicación es? así te podemos aconsejar de como desacoplar parte del código

Comment: lo estoy haciendo con express el módulo de node.js

Comment: Vale, te voy a agregar una respuesta con un ejemplo y como solucionarlo para que sea síncrono.

Comment: ¿Cada vez que se llama a `mostrarDatos()` se realizará una conexión a Mongo? Eso no es buena práctica si al finalizar dicha función no desconectas de Mongo. Por otro lado, toda solicitud a DB (sea Mongo, SQL, FireStore, etc.) siempre será asíncrona. Lo que debes hacer es documentarte en el uso de procesos asíncronos, no intentar convertir el día en noche. Cuando entiendas a fondo este concepto, todo lo que te plantees con procesos de este tipo lo harás con los ojos cerrados. Saludos

Comment: Así es, como dice @MauricioContreras no creo que puedas quitar esa asincronía. Yo no lo recomendaría por no bloquear hilos en el servidor. Lo que puedes hacer es usar async - await. De este modo serás capaz de escribir tu código como si hubiese una respuesta síncrona, sin uso de callbacks etc. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que hemos hablado en los comentarios, estás usando express como servidor web. Te recomiendo que levantes la conexión de mongodb a la par que levantas el servidor de express. Te adjunto aquí un ejemplo:

En este ejemplo uso el método [.connect()](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/mongoclient.html#MongoClient.connect) del driver de mongodb para node

Te muestro un ejemplo con las capas un poco más separadas. En tu index.js, es tu fichero principal, haces la conexión con tu bbdd, después si la conexión fue exitosa injectas el cliente a tu clase DAO y arrancas el servidor express

**index.js**

```
import app from "./server"
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb"
import MostrarDatosDAO from "../src/dao/mostrarDatosDAO"

MongoClient.connect(urlMongo, {useUnifiedTopology: true ,fsync: true})
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err.stack)
    process.exit(1)
  })
  .then(async client => {
    await MostrarDatosDAO.injectDB(client);
    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Servidor express corriendo en: ${port}`);
    })
  });
```

En tu server express, montas los enrutadores para cada entidad, he cogido de ejemplo lo que expones de "mostrarDatos" y le pasamos las rutas de *"mostrarDatos.route.js"*

**server.js**

```
import express from "express"
import mostrarDatos from "../src/api/mostrarDatos.route"


const app = express()
app.use("/api/v1/mostrarDatos", mostrarDatos)
```

Aquí indicamos que para el get de todas llame al método mostrarDatos del controlador *"mostrarDatos.controller.js"*

**mostrarDatos.route.js**

```
import { Router } from "express";
import MostrarDatosCtrl from "./mostrarDatos.controller";

const router = new Router();

router.route("/").get(MostrarDatosCtrl.mostrarDatos);


export default router;
```

En nuestro controlador llamamos al método del DAO encargado de ejecutar de forma síncrona a través del await la función que pides
**mostrarDatos.controller.js**

```
import MostrarDatosDAO from "../dao/mostrarDatosDAO"

export default class MostrarDatosController {
    static async mostrarDatos(req, res, next) {
        res.json(await MostrarDatosDAO.mostrarDatos(sentencia));
    }
}
```

Aquí por último estaría la respuesta a tu pregunta de como se haría:

**mostrarDatosDAO.js**

```
let test;
export default class MostrarDatosDAO {
    static async injectDB(conn) {
        if (test) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            test = await conn.db('test').collection("test")
            this.test = test;
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(`Error al conectar: ${e}`);
        }
   }


    static async mostrarDatos(sentencia) {
        try {
            const tipos = await test.find(sentencia).toArray();
            const tipo = tipos[0].tipo;
            console.log("Dentro" + tipo);
            return tipos[0].tipo;
        } catch (e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

He preferido añadirte un ejemplo completo separando responsabilidades por si te vale de referencia para estructurar un poco mejor el proyecto. No es la mejor arquitectura pero te vale de referencia un poco.

Comment: muchas grasias a todos ustedes, ya esta solucionado el "fallo".

Answer (score 0):

Hola amigo aquí te puedo dejar la configuración de una base de datos que tengo por si te llega en algún momento servir:

MongoDB:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { mongodb } = require('./keys');

mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.connect(mongodb.URI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true
})
  .then(db => console.log('DB is connected'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Keys:

```
module.exports = {
  mongodb: {
    URI: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/TuBaseDeDatos'
  }
};
```

Server:

```
 const express = require('express');
   const app = express();
   require('./database');

   app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3002);

   app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
   console.log('server on port', app.get('port'));
   });
```